# How to check if current static page is frontpage from admin plugin

Tags: plugin-development, frontpage, homepage

I set static page as front page.

I need to know if user currently on homepage in my custom plugin.

Functions **is_home()** and **is_front_page()** doesn't works, since homepage is static page.

I can get an id of this page :

```
$frontpage_id = get_option('page_on_front');
```

But how to get id of current page from admin plugin? (Then i'll be able to compare those ids and detect if current page is homepage!)

2 vancoder
Code:

1) Set any static page as frontpage.

2) Create dummy plugin

3) Code of plugin :

```
$d = is_front_page();
var_dump($d);

==> 

bool(false)
```

**UPD**

http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#The_Front_Page

should work, by didn't

2 Vancoder

Admin plugin means just plugin :) sorry

And those two lines is all context for now, try it yourself, it doesn't works.

WP version 3.3.2

Comment: `is_front_page()` should work. Can you show some of your code?

Comment: I think you need to show your code in more context. is_front_page should work.

Comment: What does your question mean by _admin_ plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is why I asked for more code context. I'll have to guess that you are checking for the front page outside of any hooked function, or inside a function that is called too early, before is_front_page() is ready.

The following will work.

```
function your_function()  {
$d = is_front_page();
var_dump($d);
}

add_action( 'wp', 'your_function' );
```

Comment: It works!!! Tnx, mate, saved a lot of time :)

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are talking about the editor screen? If so, you can use the global variable `$post_ID`:

```
add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', 'wpse_94626_front_page_detection' );

function wpse_94626_front_page_detection()
{
    global $post_ID, $post_type;

    if ( empty ( $post_ID ) or 'page' !== $post_type )
        return;

    if ( $post_ID === (int) get_option( 'page_on_front' ) )
        print '<p><b>This is the front page!</b></p>';
}
```

[image]

Comment: No, i talk about: when user loads any page on frontend, i should detect if this is homepage (in my custom plugin)

Comment: @sbxmal You cannot get to the front page _page_; WordPress will redirect that request to the front page automatically, and then `is_front_page()` is `true`.

Comment: Maybe, i explained this not really clearly. I have plugin with code above ($d = is_front_page(); var_dump($d);). When i go to homepage of the site, i want to check in plugin is it really homepage or any other page. Homepage is set as static page.